# Difference between a system with infinite solutions and an indefinite system

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

What is the difference between a system with infinite solutions and an indefinite system? Could someone give me an explanation with examples?

Comment: It might be easier to get a good answer if you include in the question what you mean by an indefinite system since this is non-standard terminology (as far as I'm aware)

Comment: @IsAdisplayName The lines resulting from the solution of the system coincide (are identical). So they have all their points in common and therefore the system has infinite solutions. In this case, we say that the system is indefinite.

Comment: It is not true that if a system results in identical lines (presumably after Gaussian elimination) then the system will necessarily have infinitely many solutions. ("Infinite solutions"$\neq$ "infinitely many solution"; the solutions themselves will usually be finite quantities). For example, the system $x+y=2$, $x+2y=3$, $x+2y=3$ results in identical lines, but has exactly one solution.